# Puppet - recognize new build versions and deploy

Tags: deployment, build, version, puppet

I have a puppet master sources my application builds into a master folder.  for eg.  xxxxx_v1.0.0.zip and yyyyy_v1.0.8.zip [xxxxx gets deployed to a ser of servers and yyyyy to another set of servers].

What is the best way to handle sourcing on puppet master on new versions of my application builds, without editing the .pp files on the master to reference the new build number on the filename, preferably, automatic.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A good way to build a suitable package for your operating system instead. Puppet can use those with

```
package { 'application-x': ensure => latest }
```

Failing that, you solve this

- on the agent side, by fetching your application metadata from somewhere, e.g. with an `exec` of `wget`, then having it run a script to perform the deployment if necessary
- on the master side using an ENC like the Puppet Dashboard, or better yet, [Hiera](http://docs.puppetlabs.com/hiera/1/), to hold your latest version information

If you really want to do this through Puppet's `fileserver` without touching any metadata and just dropping the files in your modules, you can try with the generate function.

```
$latest_zip_application_x = generate("/usr/local/bin/find_latest application_x")
file { 'application_x.zip':
    ...
    source => "puppet:///modules/application_x/path/to/$latest_zip_application_x",
}
```

where `/usr/local/bin/find_latest` is a script that will find the most recent version of your package and write it to stdout.

This is pretty horrible practice though - you are really not catering to Puppet's strengths with constructs like these.

Comment: Thanks Felix.  I am asking more from master side, how do I pick up a new build that got dropped in the folder(on master) for deployment.  Any pointers?   btw, I also use mco.

Comment: @user1882828 I updated my answer to include an (ugly) alternative.